# C# Asp.Net Webservice throws Exception when switching from Debug to Release Mode

Tags: c#, web-services, debugging, release

My webservice is working perfectly on Debug mode but when I switched it to Release mode it throws exception,

> Exception 1   The type or namespace name 'example1' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Exception 2   The type or namespace name 'example2' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have no idea why this is happening? Any help will be appropriated.

Comment: what is example1 and example2?

Comment: MailClient and Trace...but does that matter?
Edit: now i rebuild and got way more errors..same type but different name(Trace,MailClient,..)
I think the reason for this is the webservice...but i don't know why

Comment: Most likely you have different project settings for different configurations. Verify your configuration manager.

Comment: Config Manager:
MyProject Release x86 Build:checked
switchting to Debug
MyProject Debug x86 Build:checked
That should be correct right?

Comment: Have you made sure that required DLL files or other required file are copied to the output Release folder? That means Output folder must contains exactly the same dll or required file in both debug and release mode.

Comment: Edit:
Maybe you should write an answer not a comment so others can see the solution better?
-
While lunch i talked to a colleague and he said try to copy that .dll in your release folder and that solved my problem. so same idea like you @Rezoan (i will mark your comment as useful)
Thought VS2010 would copy all files needed by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So make sure projects output folder must contains exactly the same dll or required file in both debug and release mode. Made copy local = true to the required .dll files form properties window. it will always copy your .dll files to the output directory while building the projects.